# Implementing strong params using Dropwizard

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I would like to validate the request in a way that only specific request fields should be accepted and return 400 for all the non-accepted fields using Dropwizard and Jersey.

Is there anyway to do this?

EDIT:

Example - Lets assume the request contains the following JSON:
{ 
name: Test,
age: 30,
id: 52
}

and the field id is not accepted in the request by the server.

Expected: The server should return 400 stating that the field id is not allowed in the request.

Answer (score 1):

**Second try to answer this question after question was edited.**

You can build your JSON bean and ignore unknown values like ID with Jackson annotation 'JsonIgnoreProperties'.

You have following resource:

```
@Post
public Response hello(Person person) {
        return Response
                .status(Status.OK)
                .entity(String.format("Hello %s. We know that you are %s years old, but we do not know if you send more informations to us like id or sth. else.", person.getName(), person.getAge()))
                .build();
}
```

---

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    @JsonCreator
    public Person(@JsonProperty String name,@JsonProperty int age) {
        this.name= name;
        this.age= age;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getage() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

---

**Old Answer:**

Why not validate them? Below 3 example of how to do this.

**Option 1:**

```
@Path("smooth")
@GET
public Response smooth(
    @DefaultValue("2") @QueryParam("step") int step,
    @DefaultValue("true") @QueryParam("min-m") boolean hasMin,
    @DefaultValue("true") @QueryParam("max-m") boolean hasMax,
    @DefaultValue("true") @QueryParam("last-m") boolean hasLast,
    @DefaultValue("blue") @QueryParam("min-color") ColorParam minColor,
    @DefaultValue("green") @QueryParam("max-color") ColorParam maxColor,
    @DefaultValue("red") @QueryParam("last-color") ColorParam lastColor) {
    validateMaxColor(maxColor);
}

public void validateMaxColor(ColorParam  maxColorParam){
    if(!maxColorParam.isInRange()){
        throw new WebapplicationException("maxColorParam out of range");
    }
}
```

**Option 2:Use a specific param class**

```
@Path("smooth")
@GET
public Response smooth(
    @DefaultValue("2") @QueryParam("step") int step,
    @DefaultValue("true") @QueryParam("min-m") boolean hasMin,
    @DefaultValue("true") @QueryParam("max-m") boolean hasMax,
    @DefaultValue("true") @QueryParam("last-m") boolean hasLast,
    @DefaultValue("blue") @QueryParam("min-color") ColorParam minColor,
    @DefaultValue("green") @QueryParam("max-color") ColorParam maxColor,
    @DefaultValue("red") @QueryParam("last-color") ColorParam lastColor) {
    ....
}


public class ColorParam extends Color {

    public ColorParam(String color) {
        super(getRGB(color));
        if(getRGB(color).isGreen()){
            throw new ParseException("ohh nooooo ... green is not allowed here");
        }
    }

    private static int getRGB(String s) {
        if (s.charAt(0) == '#') {
            try {
                Color c = Color.decode("0x" + s.substring(1));
                return c.getRGB();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new WebApplicationException(400);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                Field f = Color.class.getField(s);
                return ((Color)f.get(null)).getRGB();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new WebApplicationException(400);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here it is important that you use a String constructor.

**Option 3: For Dropwizard Users; Use AbstractParam and validate the incoming string**

See [Dropwizard documentation about Params](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.0/docs/manual/core.html#parameters):

> Parameters
>
> The annotated methods on a resource class can accept parameters which
>   are mapped to from aspects of the incoming request. The *Param
>   annotations determine which part of the request the data is mapped,
>   and the parameter type determines how the data is mapped.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> A @PathParam("user")-annotated String takes the raw value from the user variable in the matched URI template and passes it into the
> ```
>
> method as a String.
>       A @QueryParam("count")-annotated IntParam parameter takes the first count value from the request’s query string and passes it as a
>   String to IntParam‘s constructor. IntParam (and all other
>   io.dropwizard.jersey.params.* classes) parses the string as an
>   Integer, returning a 400 Bad Request if the value is malformed.
>       A @FormParam("name")-annotated Set parameter takes all the name values from a posted form and passes them to the method as a set
>   of strings.
>       A *Param–annotated NonEmptyStringParam will interpret empty strings as absent strings, which is useful in cases where the endpoint
>   treats empty strings and absent strings as interchangeable.
>
> What’s noteworthy here is that you can actually encapsulate the vast
>   majority of your validation logic using specialized parameter objects.
>   See AbstractParam for details.

Your resource should get something like this:

```
@Path("long")
@GET
public Response long(
    @QueryParam("long") LongParam longValue) {
    //here your longValue is in wanted Range
    //doubles or floats will return a HTTP 400
}


/**
 * A parameter encapsulating long values. All non-decimal values will return a {@code 400 Bad
 * Request} response.
 */
public class LongParam extends AbstractParam<Long> {
    public LongParam(String input) {
        super(input);
    }

    @Override
    protected String errorMessage(Exception e) {
        return "Parameter is not a number.";
    }

    @Override
    protected Long parse(String input) {
        return Long.valueOf(input);
    }
}
```

With this you can easily validate your incoming string and throw an exception if string can not be parsed or is not valid range (e.g. if you want a HexValue and your string is #ZZ8000, then you can check that hex string is not allowed to contain any 'Z').

Comment: Hi hiaclibe. I am facing issue in writing an inclusion validator. I have to validate a param in the request to contain only a value from a list. For example: "degree" is a request param that can contain only values in [B.E, BSC, UG, PG, etc]

Comment: @Vicky: Please ask a new question. Your new requirements are unclear, and are a superset of those you originally stated in your question.